# Why `resolve-path c:` is different from `resolve-path c:\` and is also different from `resolve-path d:` in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface

I am using `Resolve-Path` on Windows PowerShell.
The commands `Resolve-Path c:\` and `Resolve-Path d:\` will return as I expect:

```
Resolve-Path c:\
# Path
# ----
# C:\

Resolve-Path d:\
# Path
# ----
# D:\
```

But if I omit `\`, the results are very confusing:

```
cd $Home
Resolve-Path c:
# Path
# ----
# C:\Users\xxx

cd D:\Desktop\
Resolve-Path d:
# Path
# ----
# D:\Desktop

cd c:\
Resolve-Path c:
# Path
# ----
# C:\
Resolve-Path d:
# Path
# ----
# D:\Desktop

cd d:\
Resolve-Path d:
# Path
# ----
# D:\
Resolve-Path c:
# Path
# ----
# C:\
```

Why? Why there is no guarantee that the `Resolve-Path c:` and `Resolve-Path d:` without `\` in the end can return the corresponding dirve's root path?

I'm very confused about this. It does not seem to be a problem unique to `Resolve-Path`, but also to `Convert-Path`. I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `C:` describes "the whole drive" without any specific path - so PowerShell grabs the current value of that drives' _location stack_. This is by design. If you want the root of the drive, specify the root path: eg. C:\

Comment: In a *dos* command prompt, ```dir c:``` would list the contents of the *current directory* (a.k.a working directory) on that drive. Looks like.PowerShell does the same thing for ```Resolve-Path```. If you specifically mean the root directory you have to refer it with a trailing backslash…

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. That may be the reason that my test results are always changing. Thank you for your answer. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only provide the drive, PowerShell uses the current location of that PSDrive.

```
Get-PSDrive | Select-Object Name, CurrentLocation
```

If you want to get the *root* of the drive, use the directory separator to indicate you're referring to the root directory instead of the 'current location on the drive'.